# How to do theatre seat reservation in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm a beginner in C++ and still learning. My teacher has assigned me a project and I'm trying to create a cinema's software. I'm done with the basic options and the menus. Now I'm stuck at the seat reservation. I managed to create a simple reservation system using array's which X's the seat that the user wants to book. It also displays an error if it is being booked again or an invalid seat is selected that does not exist. Now I don't know how to display the specific seat number like "A1" "C3"?

I'm just a beginner and I'm going to use a specific separate function in my project but the code I'm posting here is itself the main function.

Thank You! PS: I know my code isn't as efficient as it needs to be but I made this only while practicing for the real program...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    choose:
    string seat[]={"x1","y1","x2","y2","x3","y3","x4","y4","x5","y5","x6","y6","x7","y7","x8","y8","x9","y9","x10","y10","x11","y11","x12","y12","x13","y13","x14","y14","x15","y15","x16","y16","x17","y17","x18","y18","x19","y19","x20","y20","x21","y21","x22","y22","x23","y23","x24","y24","x25","y25","x26","y26","x27","y27","x28","y28","x29","y29","x30","y30","x31","y31","x32","y32","x33","y33","x34","y34","x35","y35","x36","y36"};
    int row,col;
    int input;
    char rows='1';
    char c;
    char book1;
    string arr[4][9]={{"[ ]","[ ]","[ ]","[ ]","[ ]","[ ]","[ ]","[ ]","[ ]"},{"[ ]","[ ]","[ ]","[ ]","[ ]","[ ]","[ ]","[ ]","[ ]"},
    {"[ ]","[ ]","[ ]","[ ]","[ ]","[ ]","[ ]","[ ]","[ ]"},{"[ ]","[ ]","[ ]","[ ]","[ ]","[ ]","[ ]","[ ]","[ ]"}};
    cout<<"\t\t            1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9"<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<4; ++i)
    {
        cout<<"\t\t   Row "<<rows<<":  ";
        ++rows;
        for(int j=0; j<9; ++j)
            cout<<arr[i][j]<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
    }

    again:
    rows='1';
    for(input=1; input<37; input=input+2)
    {
        rows='1';
        cout<<endl<<"\t\t               Enter Row & Column: ";
        cin>>row>>col;
        if (row<=0 || col<=0)
        {
            cout<<endl<<"\t\t              Please Pick A Valid Seat"<<endl;
            Sleep(500);
            system("cls");
            goto choose;
        }
        --row;
        --col;
        if(arr[row][col]=="[X]")
        {
            cout<<endl<<"\t\t             Seat Not Available"<<endl;
            goto again;
        }
        arr[input][input+1]=arr[row][col];
        arr[row][col]="[X]";
        system("cls");
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"\t\t            1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9"<<endl;
        for(int i=0; i<4; ++i)
        {
            cout<<"\t\t   Row "<<rows<<":  ";
            ++rows;
            for(int j=0; j<9; ++j)
               cout<<arr[i][j]<<" ";
            cout<<endl;
        }
        cout<<endl<<"\t\t                   Seat Booked!"<<endl;
        cout<<endl<<"\t\t        Do You Want To Book Another Seat?"<<endl;
        cout<<"\t\t          Press [Y] For Yes & [N] For No."<<endl;
        cout<<"\t\t                        ";

        cin>>c;
        if(c=='y' || c=='Y')
            continue;
        else if(c=='n' || c=='N')
        // Here I want the code to print seat number as A1 or C3 etc...
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @stark i used that on my own and as I said I'm a "beginner".

Comment: Please see this example http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/146160/

Comment: @stark Judging and coercion are not as helping as saying why it's "bad". Goto exists as fundamental operator for processors (you got them is all programs with if//else/switch control, in their compiled assembly form), it also exists in many languages but it makes the readability and debuggability harder, therefore it's not a recommended practice.

Comment: thank you @Soleil so what can i do instead of using goto? for example when a user enters 5 but my menu only supports options till the inputs 1-4?

Comment: @Umair You can use switch. The ideal situation would be to separate 1) the keyboard entry processing 2) the data processing 3) the display. That's not part of your question but thinking and coding this way early (learning journey) is valuable. In that case, it's easy to test each aspect and to change it. It increases also a lot the readability (each class has one responsability). In c++ you can use interfaces (virtual methods), and implementations that override the interface. With your problem example, it should be straight. You might want check out SOLID, dependency injection and unit tests.

Comment: @Umair If you have conditions involving an range (eg., choice>=5), `switch` won't be useful, but rather `if`. But you can combine both (`if` to sort correct/incorrect choice, and switch for choice \in [1-4]), or use just switch with a `default` for wrong conditions (choice \not \in [1-4]).

Comment: http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display letters instead of numbers then you can use array of those letters:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    static const char letters[] = "ABCDEFGHIJ";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        std::cout << "#" << i << " is " << letters[i] << '\n';
    }
}
```

That will display:

```
#0 is A
#1 is B
#2 is C
#3 is D
#4 is E
#5 is F
#6 is G
#7 is H
#8 is I
#9 is J
```

Note that array indexing in C++ starts from 0.
So if you want to display your row number 1 as A and 2 as B etc. then you need to subtract 1 from your row number like `letters[row_number - 1]`. But better learn to think like programmer that first thing is at index 0, second is at index 1 and so on.

```
#include <iostream>

void display(int row, int seat)
{
    static const char letters[] = "ABCDEFGHIJ";
    std::cout << letters[row - 1] << seat;
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        std::cout << "#" << i << " is ";
        display(i, i);
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks i modified a bit of your code to get the exact coordinate of the reserved seats but it's as 1 1 and now im trying to display A 1 instead of 1 1. can you help?

Comment: Added explanation to end of my answer.